# Invalid input when integer is within valid means?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm working on a VB program, rather basic (no pun intended), in which I need to convert basic integers to Roman numerals.  I have the conversion part working perfectly with my Select Case.  I also need to add validation input so if an invalid number is entered, the text box displays as such.  Any number between 1 and 10 should result in the ability to click the convert button.  Currently, any number I enter between 1 and 10 immediately displays, "That number is invalid."

This is my current code, which fails:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub lblRomanNum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub txtBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox1.TextChanged
    Dim intNum As Integer
    If intNum < 1 Or intNum > 10 Then
        txtBox1.Text = "That number is invalid."
        'ElseIf intNum > 10 Then
        'txtBox1.Text = "That number is invalid"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub btnConvert_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
Select CInt(txtBox1.Text)
        Case 1                      ' numerical 1
            txtBox2.Text = "I"
        Case 2                      ' numerical 2
            txtBox2.Text = "II"
        Case 3                      ' numerical 3
            txtBox2.Text = "III"
        Case 4                      ' numerical 4
            txtBox2.Text = "IV"
        Case 5                      ' numerical 5
            txtBox2.Text = "V"
        Case 6                      ' numerical 6
            txtBox2.Text = "VI"
        Case 7                      ' numerical 7
            txtBox2.Text = "VII"
        Case 8                      ' numerical 8
            txtBox2.Text = "VIII"
        Case 9                      ' numerical 9
            txtBox2.Text = "IX"
        Case 10                     ' numerical 10
            txtBox2.Text = "X"
            'Case Else
            'If a user enters an invalid value, this message is displayed and no conversion is attempted, according to instructions.
            'txtBox2.Text = "That value is invalid."
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub lblRomanNum_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
End Class
```

Any intNum less than 1 should display the invalid message.

Any intNum greater than 10 should display the invalid message.

If I'm reading what I currently have correctly, this should work and allow me to enter a number between 1 and 10 without the invalid message appearing.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Try the brackets and the 'or'

```
1. Dim intNum As Integer
2.    If (intNum < 1) or (intNum > 10) Then
3.        txtBox1.Text = "That number is invalid."
4.    End If
```

Comment: Unexplainably, your suggestion is still resulting in an invalid message.

Comment: Then you need to display the value you are getting in another control; maybe it is not what you think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your code perfectly worked for me in Visual Studio 2013 with .NET Framework 4.5.1. Try deleting entire block and re-type the code.
Or you can try this code as well

```
 If intNum < 1 OrElse intNum > 10 Then
    TextBox1.Text = "That number is invalid."
 End If
```

Comment: Unexplainably, your suggestion is still resulting in an invalid message also.

Comment: You have changed the question.  `Dim intNum As Integer`  is the declaration, `intNum` it is always 0. So the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add...

```
 Integer.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, i)
```

...directly under my variable declaration.